# Why is jquery dialog-message refreshing my page unwantedly (inside form)

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

i am trying to embed a simple jquery dialog-message into a form. The dialog should only show some additional information and not interact with the form in any way except beeing called via a button from inside the form.

My problem is the following: If the dialog is called from inside the form the whole page gets refreshed instantly, not showing the dialog at all and clearing all form fields. If the button is outside the form everything is working just fine.

The dialog content is being loaded via templates like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var dlg = $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '80%',
        closeOnEscape: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        open: function() {
            // Content laden...
            $("#dialog-message").load('template.html', function() {}).dialog()
        }
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
</script>
```

The form integration:

```
<form method="post" name="post" action="index.php?site=bewerbung">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="$border">

  ...

  </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="$bg1">
    <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input class="input" type="checkbox" name="rules" id="rules" value="1" /><button id="opener">Regeln</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: button default action.  use $( "#opener" ).click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button submits the form, so you need to prevent the default button action via JavaScript:

```
$("#opener").on('click', function(e) {
    dlg.dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You don't mentioned what jQuery (UI) version you are using. My code above is for the newer versions.
Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cyAgm/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally for Buttons and Submit-inputs: you can prevent the refreshing of the page, if you place "return false;" on the end of your function. In your case

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
```